# How to set endpoint to handle websockets in express behind nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

**Edit:** I have continued searching around, and got a bit further. Now when calling my endpoint, I get the following error:

```
GET /?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LhnJ9p5 404
```

So now it does ends up in the right place, but it executes a polling request instead of a ws connection. Still, calling the backend directly works fine, but going through Nginx screws up my request.

**Client**

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

...

//Does work
io.connect('localhost:10007');
// Does not work
io.connect('http://localhost', {path:'/my/path'});

socket.on('connect', function(){console.log('Connected!');});
socket.on('event', function(data){console.log('Data: ', data);});
socket.on('disconnect', function(){console.log('Disconnected!');});
```

**Server**

```
// Lots of initiation, middleware, routing etc.
let app = express.init('src/'); 

let server = http.createServer( app );
var io = require( "socket.io" )( server );

server.listen(10007,'127.0.0.1');

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log("User Connected");
});
```

**nginx.conf**

```
location /my/path/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:10007/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Looking through the internet and SO I stumble upon similar questions, and all just seem to point to the configuration in nginx.conf. While it seems to work well for others, I am missing something else.

---

I have a backend set up behind a Nginx proxy. The backend is based on express and works like an API handling different calls to GET/POST/DELETE etc. Nginx sets up the proxy to forward the calls to the backend server, and all is well.

Now I need to implement a websocket connection to the backend, and I don't seem to get it right. The calls never get through to the backend, and I don't know why. Here is my server code:

```
function setRoutes(app) {

...

  /**
   * Set up socket.io to the endpoint
  */
  let server = require('http').Server(app);
  let io = require('socket.io')(server);
  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('Client is connected: ', socket);
  });
  // If I uncomment this, I am able to connect to localhost:80 on the client
  //server.listen(80);
}
```

As stated in the comments above, if I ignore the server backend setup, and bypass it by directly listen to port 80 on localhost, the websocket connection works. But all the other endpoints are removed from their proxied address in Nginx. I would like the websocket to connect to the same endpoint address that is used by the rest of the server.

Reading up a bit on this, I noticed a walk trough on this [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio/), but this seems to set a whole endpoint for the websocket, whereas I would like to define my routing in my express code, not in my Nginx setup. For example, if I would like setup several different websocket endpoints to the same proxy, I would have to manage routing on two different places. I would like to stay away from this if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stumbled upon your issue while trying to debug my socket.io issue... Mine is setup on AWS using nginx so hopefully these'll help.

I believe the key to getting websocket to work in nginx is the upstream configuration:

```
upstream ws_NodeAppName {
    ip_hash;
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}


   location ~ ^/(NodeAppName|NodeAppName\/socket.io) {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://ws_NodeAppName;
}
```

A caveat of my approach is that the page the client receives is not served from the node app, so the node app is simply setting up the socket.

If setup this way, you'll need to explicitly specify the path to the socket.

CLIENT:

```
var socket = io.connect(window.location.origin,
{
    path: '/NodeAppName/socket.io'
});
```

SERVER:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http, {
    path: '/NodeAppName/socket.io'
});
```

I hope that helps! It can be bastardly trying to get this properly configured.. I'm tumbling down the rabbit hole trying to determine what's causing sporadic 504 errors for mine.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I have bee nassigned another task during this time, so I just returned to handle this issue. And you explanation did solve my issue, but I can't put my finger on what differs from my test and tries. But my problem now is that when trying the same setup on our test platform, this fails with the same reaction... But as this question already have increased to and beyond readability, I will ans a new question with the new information.